# Странный шаблон .bootstrap

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным должно быть колонки. Как сделать что бы оно было как в макете на половину за пределами колонки? или это не бутстраповский шаблон вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут скорее дизайнер не заморачивался с сеткой, используй smart-grid Лаврика, там можно вручную параметры сетки настраивать